# Redmine installation problem on Windows 7

Tags: .net, windows, bug-tracking, redmine

I installed Ruby 1.8.7

Installed rails 2.3.11 and rack 1.1.0 and 1.1.1'

See below list of local gems

C:\Ruby187\Apps\Redmine>gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (2.3.11, 2.0.0)
actionpack (2.3.11, 2.0.0)
activerecord (2.3.11, 2.0.0)
activeresource (2.3.11)
activesupport (2.3.11, 2.0.0)
i18n (0.6.0, 0.4.2)
mysql (2.8.1 x86-mingw32)
rack (1.1.2, 1.1.1, 1.1.0)
rails (2.3.11)
rake (0.9.2)
sqlite3 (1.3.3 x86-mingw32)
sqlite3-ruby (1.3.3)

installed mysql and created readmine database

This is the problem I am getting;

C:\Ruby187\Apps\Redmine>rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV

rake/rdoctask is deprecated.  Use rdoc/task instead (in RDoc 2.4.2+)
WARNING: 'task :t, arg, :needs => [deps]' is deprecated.  Please use 'task :t, [
args] => [deps]' instead.
    at C:/Ruby187/Apps/Redmine/lib/tasks/email.rake:170
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- sqlite

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

content of database.yml file under readmine/config

production:
  adapter: mysql
  database: redmine
  host: localhost
  username: root
  password: korkimysql
  encoding: utf8

development:
  adapter: mysql
  database: redmine_development
  host: localhost
  username: root
  password: korkimysql
  encoding: utf8

appreciate any help

C:\Ruby187\Apps\Redmine>rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV --trace results below

tring/inflections.rb:162:in `constantize'
C:/Ruby187/Apps/Redmine/vendor/rails/active
157:in`observed_class'
C:/Ruby187/Apps/Redmine/vendor/rails/active
183:in `observed_classes'
C:/Ruby187/Apps/Redmine/vendor/rails/active
166:in`initialize'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/singleton.rb:94:in
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/singleton.rb:94:in
C:/Ruby187/Apps/Redmine/vendor/rails/active
38:in `instantiate_observers'
C:/Ruby187/Apps/Redmine/vendor/rails/active
36:in`each'
C:/Ruby187/Apps/Redmine/vendor/rails/active
36:in `instantiate_observers'
C:/Ruby187/Apps/Redmine/vendor/rails/action
.rb:15:in`define_dispatcher_callbacks'
C:/Ruby187/Apps/Redmine/vendor/rails/active
rb:182:in `call'
C:/Ruby187/Apps/Redmine/vendor/rails/active
rb:182:in`evaluate_method'
C:/Ruby187/Apps/Redmine/vendor/rails/active
rb:166:in `call'
C:/Ruby187/Apps/Redmine/vendor/rails/active
rb:90:in`run'
C:/Ruby187/Apps/Redmine/vendor/rails/active
rb:90:in `each'
C:/Ruby187/Apps/Redmine/vendor/rails/active
rb:90:in`send'
C:/Ruby187/Apps/Redmine/vendor/rails/active
rb:90:in `run'
C:/Ruby187/Apps/Redmine/vendor/rails/active
rb:276:in`run_callbacks'
C:/Ruby187/Apps/Redmine/vendor/rails/action
.rb:51:in `send'
C:/Ruby187/Apps/Redmine/vendor/rails/action
.rb:51:in`run_prepare_callbacks'
C:/Ruby187/Apps/Redmine/config/../vendor/ra
n `prepare_dispatcher'
C:/Ruby187/Apps/Redmine/config/../vendor/ra
n`process'
C:/Ruby187/Apps/Redmine/config/../vendor/ra
n `send'
C:/Ruby187/Apps/Redmine/config/../vendor/ra
n`run'
C:/Ruby187/Apps/Redmine/config/environment.
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/
_require'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/
C:/Ruby187/Apps/Redmine/vendor/rails/active
es.rb:182:in `require'
C:/Ruby187/Apps/Redmine/vendor/rails/active
es.rb:547:in`new_constants_in'
C:/Ruby187/Apps/Redmine/vendor/rails/active
es.rb:182:in `require'
C:/Ruby187/Apps/Redmine/vendor/rails/railti
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.
h_call_chain'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in`
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.
h_call_chain'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.
requisites'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.
requisites'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.
h_call_chain'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.
h_call_chain'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.
oke_task'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.
level'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.
'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.
level'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.
ndard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.
level'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.

C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.
ndard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.

C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.
C:/Ruby187/bin/rake:19:in `load'
C:/Ruby187/bin/rake:19
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment

Comment: Have you fixed your problem yet? I am busy installing Redmine on Windows 7 as well. I will let  you know if I encounter this problem. I have encountered the same problem with Vista, but I remember that at one point I could continue despite the warning.

Answer (score 1):

downgrading(uninstall and install) rake version to 0.8.7 solved this ..

Answer (score 0):

While developing our [BitNami Redmine Stack](http://bitnami.org/stack/redmine) we also ran into the same issue you mentioned and we also ship Ruby 1.8.7 and rake 0.8.7.